# Editing row in child nested gridview in C#

Tags: c#, gridview, edit

I need editing row on nested ( child ) gridview.

This is my code but the editing open always the same id :

> SELECT * FROM doTable WHERE sID IN ('72')

How to do resolve this ?

```
//On Gridview g1
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" Visible="false">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblsID" Text='<%# Eval("sID") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

protected void GridView2_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView g2 = (GridView)sender;
    g2.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

    int customerId = (int)g1.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex].Value;

    sql = @String.Format(" SELECT * FROM `doTable` ");
    sql += String.Format(" WHERE sID IN ('{0}') ", customerId);

    Response.Write(sql);

    g2.DataSource = GetData(sql);
    g2.DataBind();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try this :

```
    protected void GridView2_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView g2 = (GridView)sender;
        g2.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

        GridViewRow gvCustomerRow = g2.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
        int customerId = (int)g1.DataKeys[gvCustomerRow.RowIndex].Value;

        sql = @String.Format(" SELECT * FROM `doTable` ");
        sql += String.Format(" WHERE sID IN ('{0}') ", customerId);

        g2.DataSource = GetData(sql);
        g2.DataBind();
    }
```